# Windows ServiceBus 1.1 for Windows Server

Tags: powershell, servicebus

I did move the databases from our ServiceBus test enviroment.
I started by leaving the farm with the single node, then I moved the databases.

After rejoining the farm I see that GatewayDBConnectionString is till pointing to the old one.

I can't find any valid PowerShell command to reconfigure the value in question.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Problem solved by building a restore script.

Comment: any details to what your restore script looked like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this I will need you to understand this a bit more - and hence giving a high-level overview of Service Bus 1.1 Server farm configuration:

1. Service Bus Server 1.1 is a platform where users can create highly-durable distributed Pub-Sub (messaging Queues/Topics) entities. In simple words - the main job of this is to translate the Compute (your VMs) and Data (your **MsgContainer databases**) into messaging functionality Durable Queues and Topics. So, in short - the configuration wizard or the Powershell cmdlets used to configure ServiceBus 1.1 Server will try to take the VMs and Databases from you.
2. The Db **SBManagementDB** is considered to be the authoritative source of truth for any Farm level configuration -> like Nodes that are part of the Farm (Store.Nodes), Ports opened on each of the nodes, Gateway database connection string (Cluster Config) etc. Also pl. note that - as per the Windows Server product guidelines - any information that has to be securely persisted will be encrypted - so as the Gateway DB connection String.
   a) when you did New-SBFarm (with a Gateway DB connection string) - you have essentially communicated to SBMgmtDB - the Gateway DB Server, database name etc.
   b) when you do [Add-SBHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248751%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) - again you have communicated to SBMgmtDb that you want to add one Node to this Farm
3. Gateway db connection string is the one place for Truth for all Gateway Services to find any run-time info -> like Container Databases, entity to container mapping etc.
   again, when you do [New-SBMessageContainer PSCmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248759%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) --> **you communicated to SBGatewayDB that  you are adding one db**

Now, with this background - lets see how the action you did above will take into effect:
 - When you moved all the Databases to a different Server - you changed the Gateway Database connection string - But the Gateway connection string you had communicated to the SBManagementDB (using the [New-SBFarm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248757%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) cmdlet) was pointing to the Old Server. 
 - When you removed the Node from the Farm and again Joined back - you removed one node from the configuration and re-added it - no affect :)

**The ANSWER**

- Use [Restore-SBFarm PS Cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248747%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) to communicate to the SBManagementDB that you changed the GW db
- and then Use [Restore-SBMessageContainer PS Cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248767%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) to communicate to Gateway DB that you changed the Container databases.
- Now, add the Nodes back to this restored farm.

HTH!
Sree